# XML to List in C#

Tags: c#, xml

This is the xml:

```
<Packages>
  <Package>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Prerequisites>
      <Prerequisite>7</Prerequisite>
      <Prerequisite>8</Prerequisite>
    </Prerequisites>
  </Package>
    <Package>
    <Id>2</Id>
    .....
  </Package>
  ....
</Packages>
```

And the list:

```
class lista
{
public int id {get; set;}
public List<int> pre{get;set;}
}
```

How can I add This xml pattern to a list of lista class and this is what i have got so far bot it only put one in the second list.

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Employee.xml");
        var ListPckage =
            (from item in xdoc.Descendants("Package")
             orderby item.Element("Id").Value
             select new
             {
                 Id = item.Element("Id").Value,
                 Prerequisite = item.Element("Prerequisites").Element("Prerequisite").Value,
             }).ToList();
```

foreach works for shoing them

```
foreach (var item in ListPckage)
{
Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
foreach (var item1 in ListPckage)
{
Console.WriteLine(item1.Prerequisites);
}
}
```

Comment: I would start by using LINQ to XML to parse the document to an XDocument. Then write a `FromXElement` method in `lista` (which should be renamed to follow .NET naming conventions) to create an instance from an `XElement`. Hint: you'll probably want to use `Descendants(...)` or `Elements(...)` to select the `Prerequisite` elements, and just `Element` to select the `Id` element. With that set of starting hints, see how far you can get...

Comment: I would go to http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ first, create the proxy for xml and deserialize it. Later will create Mapper to map proxy to my custom class.

Answer (score 0):

As John Sket mentioned in the comment to the question, one way to achieve that is to use [Linq To Xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

```
//string xcontent = @"xml content here";
//XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xcontent);
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("FullPathToXml");
List<lista> resultlist = xdoc.Descendants("Package")
    .Select(x=> new lista
         {
             id = Convert.ToInt32(x.Element("Id").Value),
             pre = x.Descendants("Prerequisite").Select(y=>Convert.ToInt32(y.Value)).ToList()
          })
    .ToList();
```

But, i'd suggest to use [XmlSerialization/XmlDeserialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/182eeyhh(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

First parse the XML to XDocument using XDocument.Parse to get XML in XDocument variable i.e.

var requiredXml = XDocument.Parse("Xml String here")

Then you can use LINQ to Xml (something like) as below:

```
//may be syntactic error but you can get an idea

var requiredList = 
from element in requiredXml.Descandants("Package")
Select new lista { id = element.Element("ID").Value, 
pre = element.Elements("Prerequisite").Select(x=> Convert.ToInt32(x.Value)).ToList() }
```